# How to find attribute on a row table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

if I have html that integrated on php like this :

```
foreach ($data_pc as $data) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $no++ . ". "; ?> </td>
            <td class="center" data-no="<?php echo $data['id_pc'] ?>"><?php echo $data['nama_user']; ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $data['perusahaan']; ?></td>



            <td  class="left">
                <a class="btn btn-info" name="edit" title="Edit User" req_id="<?php echo $data['nama_user']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" role="button">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i> 
                </a>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-hapus" title="Hapus User" req_nama="<?php echo $data['nama']; ?>">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash" ></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

that would be representated row on table html.

I want to take the attribute `data-no` on a row. 
So, I write jquery code like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-hapus', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find row
    var data = $row.find("data-no").text(); // Find text
    alert(data);
});
```

It gives me a blank value ? How to find attribute on a row table using jquery ?

Comment: You want the value of `data-no` or the text of that row?

Comment: @tushar: i have often seen you intentally editing the question with minor changes when you answers it. what is the reason behind this?? also if you care to format the question then why don't you format it completely rather than partially??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, Might be that tushar is chasing [illuminator](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badge. And agreed minor edit would have rejected if it was in suggested edit review queue.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar You can see the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31697112/revisions). I'm just making the code look better by formatting it

Comment: @Satpal I've already got _illuminator_ badge, you can see in my profile, I've edited more than 1000 posts

Comment: @Tushar, Great then I would recommend, there is no need of trivial changes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[Has Attribute Selector [name]](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)** to target the element that have the required attribute:

```
var data = $row.find("[data-no]").text(); // get text of element that have attr data-no
```

if you want to get the attribute value of element then use `.data()` selector

```
var data = $row.find("[data-no]").data('no'); //get data attribute value
```